# How to unpack a tuple of lists

Tags: python, list, tuples, enumerate, unpack

I am attempting to unpack the elements of a list that is packed inside a tuple.

```py
myTuple = (['a', 'list', 'of', 'strings'], ['inside', 'a', 'tuple'], ['extra', 'words', 'for', 'filler'])
```

So for example I want to get this element ('a')

I have tried this:

```py
for (i, words) in list(enumerate(myTuple)):
    print(words)
```

But this returns the list like this

```
['a', 'list', 'of', 'strings']
['inside', 'a', 'tuple']
etc...
```

How can I get the elements inside the list?

Comment: You're unpacking a tuple that contains lists. To get the element inside the lists you can index the list, or iterate over it.

Comment: Do you want the output like 'a','list','of','strings','inside','a','tuple',... ?

Comment: Side-note: `for i, words in enumerate(myTuple):` is all you need to get the behavior you've got. Wrapping in `list` just makes a needless temporary, and you don't need parentheses around the `i, words` part.

Comment: @Haramoz Yes, I want the 'a', 'list', etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the indexing of your tuple and then the lists to access the inner-most elements. For example, to get at the string `'a'`, you could call:

```
myTuple[0][0]
```

If you wanted to iterate over all the elements in the lists, you could use  the `chain` method form `itertools`. For example:

```
from itertools import chain

for i in chain(*myTuple):
    print(i)
```

Comment: The `chain` was exactly what I was looking for. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`, eg. with numpy

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(append, myTuple)

Out[149]: 
array(['a', 'list', 'of', 'strings', 'inside', 'a', 'tuple', 'extra',
       'words', 'for', 'filler'], dtype='<U7')
```

Or, base

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
reduce(operator.add, myType, [])
# or, reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, myTuple)
```

`reduce` is a classic list operation function along with `map`, `filter`, etc.  It takes an initial value, here an empty list, and successively applies a function (`append`) to each element of the sequence (`myTuple`).

Comment: A very nice answer, could you please explain a little bit too, thanks :)

Comment: Ok, I added a short description. This function is pretty basic though.

Comment: Just tried this in idle real quick... Says that `append` is not defined? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, I was using numpy, I'll add one for base

Answer (score -1):

Currently you are just iterating through the entire loop and printing out the elements contained within the list.

However, if you want to access a specific element within the list then just refer to it by it’s name using .index()

Alternatively you can just print(list(indexposition))